# Ansible playbook is failing for 'become:yes'

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-inventory

The following ansible-playbook works fine for non-sudo access.
But fails when I un-comment **become:yes**

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Register the policy file in a variable
      read_csv:
        path: policy.csv
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: csv_file

    - name: Check rules pre-remediation
      command: "{{ item.Compliance_check }}"
      register: output 
      with_items:
        "{{ csv_file.list }}"

    - name: Perform remediation
      command: "{{ item.item.Remediation }}"
      when: item.item.Expected_result != item.stdout
      with_items:
        "{{ output.results }}"
```

The inventory file looks like:

```
10.136.59.110 ansible_ssh_user=username ansible_ssh_pass=password ansible_sudo_pass=password
```

Error I'm facing is:

```
user@hostname:~/git-repo/MCI$ ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i inventory 

PLAY [all] *******************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.136.59.109]

TASK [Register the policy file in a variable] ********************************************************************************************
Sorry, try again.
fatal: [10.136.59.109 -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "[sudo via ansible, key=mjcqjbcyeemygkxwycgeftiikivnylsj] password:\nsudo: no password was provided\nsudo: 1 incorrect password attempt\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************************
10.136.59.109              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Can't understand why this error is showing. I have tried providing correct sudo passwords in both inventory as well as at run-time using **--ask-become-pass**
Please help find out the cause of the error.

Comment: Try to uncomment sudo options in ansible.cfg: `sudo_flags = -H -S -n`